# Why does a property belong to a built-in overriding descriptor type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From Python in a Nutshell

> **Properties**
>
> Python supplies a **built-in** **overriding** **descriptor type**, which you may use to give a
>   class’s instances **properties**.
>
> A property is an instance attribute with special functionality.

Does the quote imply that a property belongs to a descriptor type?

If yes:

- why does a property belong to a descriptor type?
- Why does a property belong to a descriptor type which is built-in and overriding?

Comment: from my understanding of that sentence, it means that all Python classes contain a descriptor type that can be used *for* giving class instances properties - not that all properties are themselves descriptor types.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What is the "descriptor type" contained in all classes? (2) What properties are  not descriptor types? (3) What are the descriptor types which the other properties belong to?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the quote implies that `property` is a descriptor type.

What the quote means, is that there is a built-in class `property` which you can use in your Python classes to create properties. This built-in class implements the [descriptor interface](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html), and is "overriding", and is therefore an overriding descriptor type.

## What is an overriding descriptor?

A type implements the descriptor interface if it has a `__get__` method. Descriptors can also have `__set__` and `__del__` methods.

When an object attribute implements the descriptor interface, accessing the attribute like `<object>.<attribute>` will cause the `__get__` method of the descriptor attribute to run.

An "overriding" descriptor is simply a descriptor that also implements the `__set__` method, which causes `<object>.<attribute> = value` to invoke the `__set__` method of the descriptor attribute, rather than just replacing `'<attribute>'` in the object `__dict__`.

If you want to understand descriptors, [this](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#properties) is a good place to look.

## The property class

The built-in property class is usually used as a decorator, and allows you to implement getter, setter and deleter methods, but still use the property like a normal attribute:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        print("Get a")
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        print("Set a")
        self._a = value

foo = Foo(4)
b = foo.a    # b = 4, prints "Get a"
foo.a = 42   # foo._a = 42, prints "Set a"
```

To answer your questions:

- Properties are descriptors, because the property class implements the descriptor interface to allow this behaviour, which overrides the get, set and delete behaviour of the attribute. You can see an example pure python emulation of the property class [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html#properties)
- Properties are "overriding" descriptors because they implement the `__set__` method. (Even if you do not provide a setter, the property `__set__` method still exists and will throw an `AttributeError` saying that the attribute cannot be set).